# Github - Check svn revision number for git revision

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository, to which I push using git. Now, I need to take a particular revision (I know its git hash) and check it out using the svn interface. How do I figure out the corresponding svn revision number for that git revision?

Answer (score 1):

I have both an answer and a question; mostly because I am unsure of my answer. See this page: https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/

You can use the svn client against github. You kind of are clued into this when you visit a git repository and right above the URL for the repo it says "Use Git **or checkout with SVN** using the web URL."

So, do a "svn info". For example:

```
svn info https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld.git
```

That gives you a revision number. And every time you commit/merge into the git repo, the revision number gets incremented.

Now, my question is: what is this revision number based on if git doesn't "really" have one? And can we depend on it? Okay... that was two questions.

Comment: You should move your question out of the answer and ask it using the normal process of asking questions on SO.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `git` and you know the `sha` corresponding to the revision you want to checkout, then simply use

```
$ git checkout SHA
```

If you want to know the corresponding SVN revision of a git commit, simply view the git commit message.

You'll find the revision number in the [`git-svn-id` metadata](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) at the very end of the commit.

```
$ git log -1
commit 938b1a547c2cc92033b74d32030e86468294a5c8
Author: schacon <schacon@4c93b258-373f-11de-be05-5f7a86268029>
Date:   Sat May 2 22:06:44 2009 +0000

    Adding git-svn instructions to the README

    git-svn-id: file:///tmp/test-svn/trunk@79 4c93b258-373f-11de-be05-5f7a86268029
```

Note in this example the revision number is `79`.

Comment: I don't want to checkout using git. I need to checkout using svn. I cannot see git-svn-id for the commits made using git. I've ended up checking out the head using svn and then searched for the commit in svn log. This way I got the svn revision.

Comment: And Git commits don't have `git-svn-id` unless they actually originated from subversion via `git svn`.